# Ubuntu /etc/rc.local not running without sudo

Tags: ubuntu

I have a problem that when I added 'ssserver -c /etc/shadowsocks.json -d start'on /etc/rc.local, it looks like that:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

ssserver -c /etc/shadowsocks.json -d start
exit 0
```

It not work when I reboot my computer. 
But when I added sudo before "ssserver -c /etc/shadowsocks.json -d start",

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

sudo ssserver -c /etc/shadowsocks.json -d start
exit 0
```

It work very will.　
So, this is why?

Comment: Off-topic, try http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 0):

ssserver needs `sudo` privileges.

`ll /etc/shadowsocks.json`

> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 151 Dec 15 20:40 /etc/shadowsocks.json

Answer (score 0):

Whenever using `rc.local` you cannot assume that your commands are automagically recognised since the `PATH` variable is not yet loaded in some cases.

Try running the full path of the binary instead of only the name.
You can find the full path for the binary using `which ssserver`

From what I'm seeing the `shadowsocks.json` file permissions are fine since all the users can read it, in case write is also required you can run `chmod a+w /etc/shadowsocks.json` as `root` or using `sudo`.

Comment: Making a system file world-writable is never a good idea. Figure out which permissions are absolutely necessary, and assign only those.